# MySQL stored procedure on big table eats server disk space

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have inherited a MySQL InnoDB table with around 500 million rows. The table has IP numbers and the name of the ISP to which that number belongs, both as strings.

Sometimes, I need to update the name of an ISP to a new value, after company changes such as mergers or rebranding. But, because the table is so big, a simple UPDATE...WHERE  statement doesn't work - The query usually times out, or the box runs out of memory.

So, I have written a stored procedure which uses a cursor to try and make the change one record at a time. When I run the procedure on a small sample table, it works perfectly. But, when I try to run it against the whole 500 million row table in production, I can see a temporary table gets created (because a /tmp/xxx.MYI and /tmp/xxx.MYD file appear). The temporary table file keeps growing in size until it uses all available disk space on the box (around 40 GB).

I'm not sure why this temporary table is necessary. Is the server trying to maintain some kind of rollback state? My real question is, can I change the stored procedure such that the temporary table is not created? I don't really care if some, but not all of the records get updated - I can easily add some reporting and just keep running the proc until no records are altered.

At this time, architecture changes are not really an option – I can't change the structure of the table, for example.

Thanks in advance for any help.

David

This is my stored proc;

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_isp;
CREATE PROCEDURE update_isp()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_finished INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE v_num      VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT "";
  DECLARE v_isp      VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT "";

  DECLARE ip_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ip_number, isp FROM ips;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
    FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

  OPEN ip_cursor;

  get_ip: LOOP
    IF v_finished = 1 THEN
      LEAVE get_ip;
    END IF;

    FETCH ip_cursor INTO v_num, v_isp;

    IF v_isp = 'old name' THEN
      UPDATE ips SET isp = 'new name' WHERE ip_number = v_num;
    END IF;
  END LOOP get_ip;
  CLOSE ip_cursor;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL update_isp();
```

I have also tried wrapping the update statement in a transaction. It didn't make any difference.

[EDIT] My assumption below, that a simple counting procedure does not create a temporary table, was wrong. The temporary table is still created, but it grows more slowly and the box does not run out of disk space before the procedure completes.

So the problem seems to be that any use of a cursor in a  stored procedure results in a temporary table being created. I have no idea why, or if there is any way to prevent this.

Comment: How about selecting only the records you care about? you are selecting the entire table initially, than looping through all the records to find the ones matching 'old name'. Try selecting only those ones and update them in mass. This might alleviate the issue. Also indexes on the ip_number will definitely help with selecting. In the end you will end up with maybe not so much data selected for update.

Comment: Thanks, but ip_number is already the primary key. If I try to restrict to "where isp = 'old name'" the server has to scan every record of the whole table, and the query either times out or uses up all memory. Hence the idea of using a cursor so I go through the whole table and only operate on one record at a time.

Comment: depending on the number of records with the value old name, this will  not end up in a full table scan. maybe a full index scan. so a key on isp column will almost certainly help. not sure how much space will be needed for the key on disk, but is worth a try. since you have isp as a secondary key and ip_number as primary, there shouldn't be a problem of scanning the entire table since the primary key is referenced in the secondary key.

Comment: Have you tried [query_script_split](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/query_script_split.html) from [common_schema](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html)? Perhaps it's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution to this problem.

From this page; http://spec-zone.ru/mysql/5.7/restrictions_cursor-restrictions.html

> In MySQL, a server-side cursor is materialized into an internal
>   temporary table. Initially, this is a MEMORY table, but is converted
>   to a MyISAM table when its size exceeds the minimum value of the
>   max_heap_table_size and tmp_table_size system variables.

I misunderstood how cursors work. I assumed that my cursor functioned as a pointer to the underlying table. But, it seems MySQL must build the full result set first, and then give you a pointer to that. So, I don't really understand the benefits of cursors in MySQL. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

David

Answer (score 1):

If your update is essentially:

```
UPDATE ips
    SET isp = 'new name'
     WHERE isp = OLDNAME;
```

I am guessing that this `update` -- without the cursor -- will work better if you have an index on `isp(isp)`:

```
create index idx_isp_isp on isp(isp);
```

Your original query should be fine once this index is created.  There should be no performance issue updating a single row even in a very large table.  The issue is in all likelihood *finding* the row, not *updating* it.

Comment: Thanks, but the table already has that index. ip_number is the primary key.

Comment: @digitalronin . . . Then there is an issue with the `update` query that is preventing that index from being used.  How long does an equivalent `select` take?

Comment: Selecting or updating a row by its ip number is instantaneous, AFAICT.

Comment: @digitalronin . . . You are updating the `name` so you need to search by the old name.  This suggests a different query and a different index.  See the revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I don't think the problem is doing the individual updates - each one should be very quick. Finding the records shouldn't be a problem either - the cursor should handle that. Even if it takes a while (a stored proc to simply count the records took 80 minutes to run), that doesn't matter because it's not straining the server. My problem is how to prevent the temporary table I mentioned from being created, so that I can run the proc.

Answer (score 0):

If the table has some numerical index also you can specify a

```
WHERE myindex > 123 AND myindex < 456
```

in your update query and do that for a couple of intevals (with a loop for example) until the whole table is covered.

(sorry, my rep is too low to ask in the comment section, so I'll just post my guess-answer here to be able to comment on)

You could try to fake a numerical index with

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() as n, thetable.* FROM thetable ORDER BY oneofyourcolumns;
```

and then try what I suggested above.

Comment: Does you table have another numerical indexed column? If not, you can ignore my answer.

Comment: okay, then this will not work if you can't replace a missing numerical index in the table with ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: I appreciate your input, But as per my reply to Gordon Linoff, the problem really isn't the select or the individual updates.

Comment: If your COUNT didnt create the temporary tables, I'm sure my approach does not either, or at least not big ones. If you won't find an answer to you first approach eliminating the temporary tables, you could try my approach. If you do - message me or similar, and I might have time to make you a draft on how the procedure might look like. gl.